# Nested template struct constructor implementation

Tags: c++, templates, struct, nested

How do I create a nested template struct implementration?
For example, if I have:

```
foo.h:
```

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
    template<class U>
    struct bar
    {
        U u;
        bar(U u);
        ...
    };
    ...
};
```

and

```
foo.cpp
```

```
include "foo.h"
...
template<class T, class U>
foo<T>::bar<U>::bar(U u) : u(u) { }
...
```

I get different syntax errors such as "missing ';'", etc.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Templates are header only. So no cop file. If you want to implement in cop file, you need to instantiate them in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues in your code:

1. You *do* miss semicolons as error message suggests

`class` definition must be followed by a semicolon:

```
template<class T>
class foo
{
    template<class U>
    struct bar
    {
        U u;
        bar();
        ...
    };
// ~~^ here
    ...
};
// ^ and here
```

2. Class `foo<T>::bar<U>` has no constructor which takes 1 parameter. Either change your definition or implementation.
3. `template` clauses are not mergeable. If you needed 2 `template` keywords, you still need 2 of them anywhere else:

Like this:

```
template<class T>
template<class U>
foo<T>::bar<U>::bar(U u) : u(u) { }
```

4. Maybe not really an issue, because we don't see your full code, but please read [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) before you proceed.

Comment: Oh, I really missed a semicolon here, in the example, but it's not missing in the real code (and consructor params too). What did I really miss were separate template keywords. By the way: is including an implementation file in a header considered bad practice?

Comment: @EvilCasual It's explained in the question linked, and it's one of the solutions. Though I wouldn't call this file `Foo.cpp`, but rather something like `Foo.tpp`, to make it more clear why we include a non `.hpp` at the end of a `.hpp` file.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
template<class T>
template<class U>
foo<T>::bar<U>::bar(U u) : u(u) { }
```